# Spring MVC HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported - Backbone Request

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, backbone.js

I am new at Spring MVC and I am trying to build a Web Application from scratch using Spring MVC + Hibernate to serve something like a JSON Rest API, having this API consumed through Backbone at the client side. To do that I have started following this tutorial ( http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/ ) .

```
So I have a model Message which will have the following REST API Interface:
GET /api/messages               ( working ok )
GET /api/messages/:id           ( working ok )
DELETE /api/messages/:id        ( working ok )
PUT /api/messages/:id           ( working ok )
POST /api/messages              ( error: (DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:194) - Request method 'POST' not supported)
```

I expected this problem happens for PUT or DELETE requests when doing the request through a form, but not for a POST request. I am not even doing the request through a form. On the client side the request is done through Backbone like this:

```
new App.Models.Message({ attributeA : 'a', attributeB : 'b' }).save();
```

I have already tried to add the httpMethodFilter at web.xml as suggested in other Stackoverflow questions:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Has anyone had the same problem?

I leave here my MessagesController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/messages")
public class MessagesController {

    @Autowired  
    private MessageService messageService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Message> getMessagesInJSON(@RequestParam( value = "type", required = false ) String type) {   
        List<Message> messages = messageService.findAll();          
        return messages; 
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public @ResponseBody Message getMessageInJson(@PathVariable Integer id ) {      
        Message message = messageService.findById(id);
        return message;     
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE )
    @ResponseStatus( value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT )
    public void deleteMessage(@PathVariable Integer id ) throws NotFoundException {     
        messageService.delete(id);      
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT )
    @ResponseStatus( value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT )
    public void editMessage( @PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Message message ) throws NotFoundException {
        message.setId(id);
        messageService.update(message);
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public @ResponseBody Message createMessage( @RequestBody Message message ) {        
        return messageService.create(message);
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have already mapped `/api/messages` to the `getMessagesInJSON` method which only allows a GET request. Your POST request is mapping to a different path.

I suggest to omit the value attribute on your request mapping for `createMessage`.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST )
```

Comment: Yes! That was the problem. Do you know why this happens?

Thanks ;)

Comment: I haven't looked at the code but I suspect it has to do with which request mapping value matches the actual request path. To avoid this in the future it's better you never actually map to "/" but leave it empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your `@RequestMapping` is located at the top of your class definition, and conflicts with the strings that you associated with the `value` argument in the other `@RequestMapping` annotations in front of each method.  By contrast, I would start the class with the following:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(types = SomeClassName.class)
public class SomeClassNameController {
```

Then you can use the `value` parameter in the `@RequestMapping` annotations that you have in front of each method.

Answer (score 0):

It is also good to keep in mind that this error might happen if you are implementing `/error` endpoint for exception handling. If your `/error` endpoint has a method type and it doesn't match the method of the endpoint where the exception was thrown; you might end up getting 405. If that is the case, remove method type from the error endpoint to serve to all.